# Cannot find loop variable in Java

Tags: java, loops

I just started learning about loops, but I keep running into the same problem whenever I try to execute a program. Likewise, even my professor's program examples are getting the same error. Here's the program, it's just a program I was practicing with

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BaseballStats {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int SENTINEL = 0;
    int hrs = 0;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of home runs from each team: ");
        int homeruns = in.nextInt();
        if(homeruns > 0)
        {

            hrs = hrs + homeruns;
            count++;

        }
    }
    while(homeruns != SENTINEL);
    System.out.print("The average amount of home runs per team is: ");
    System.out.println(hrs / count);

}
```

}

The problem I keep getting with this program and every other loop program I try, is that the variable inside the brackets (homeruns) is not defined when outside of the brackets.

while(homeruns != SENTINEL); simply states the the symbol variable homeruns doesn't exist, and if I initialize it at the beginning of the program, it simply won't work inside the brackets because it'll say the variable already exists.

I don't know if I sound like an idiot but I'm just so incredibly confused

Comment: You are declaring `homeruns` inside your loop, so it cannot be referenced outside of it, which includes the control statement.  Just declare it right before your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare it outside the loop and then don't redeclare it inside the loop:

```
int homeruns;
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter the number of home runs from each team: ");
    //int homeruns = in.nextInt();
    homeruns = in.nextInt();
    if(homeruns > 0)
    {

        hrs = hrs + homeruns;
        count++;

    }
}
while(homeruns != SENTINEL);
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. I've literally been stuck for like hours on this. Really appreciate it.